# How to Add Default Biographical info in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Recently I ran a multi author blog where the most registered members did not fill in the biographical info. My theme has author php file. Now I want to add default biographical information which is overwritten when an author fills in the bio information himself. I am very novice in WordPress. I don't want to use any plugin. Please tell me how I can add default biographical information manually?

Answer (score 1):

You use `<?php echo get_the_author_meta('description'); ?>` to show the author description. So in your template you would do:

```
<?php if (get_the_author_meta('description')){
echo get_the_author_meta('description');
} else { ?>
Your boilerplate default
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks For Answering Me.